# Compute the left cosets of <(123)> in (S4, o).

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, symmetric-groups

I understand that H= {e, (123), (132)} and ord(H)=3. And S4 has 24 elements since 4!=24 so 24/3 means there are going to be 8 distinct cosets. I'm stuck on the multiplying part and if you say let g=(1234), then multiply gH for the first coset, then g^2H for the second coset? I'm confused as to how to find all 8 cosets.

Answer (score 3):

Finding the cosets in this small case is not so bad. First and foremost you have the coset
$$H=\{e,(123),(132)\}$$
Here is a general algorithm for how to finish. So far, say you've computed $k<8$ cosets. Pick an element of $S_4$ that is not in any of the cosets you've computed so far, and that will give you a new coset.

With this method I'll find one more coset for you. The cosets we have are
$$\{e,(123),(132)\}$$
$$\{(1234),(1234)(123)=(2413),(1234)(132)=(14)\}$$
None of the two cosets we've found contain $(234)$. So we multiply the elements of $H$ on the left by $(234)$ to get a new left coset,
$$\{(234),(24)(13),(142)\}$$
Every element of the group is in exactly one coset, so continuing in this way will get you to the end.